# Ffmpeg, Concatenate 4 videos with different codec, size and FPS

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to concatenate 4 videos with different codec, size and FPS with the below query in node.js. I have been using child_process spawn.

```
const mergeAllVideo = async () => {
try {
    const all = [
        '-y',
        '-i', './gifs_0.mp4', 
        '-i', './gifs_1.mp4', 
        '-i', './gifs_2.mp4', 
        '-i', './gifs_3.mp4', 
        '-filter_complex', "[0:v][0:a][1:v][1:a][2:v][2:a][3:v][3:a] concat=n=4:v=1:a=1 [vv] [aa]",
        '-map', '[vv]', 
        '-map', '[aa]',
        './allMerged.mp4'
    ];
    const proc = spawn(cmd, all);

    proc.stdout.on('end', function () {
        console.log("Added mergeAllVideo !!! \n");
        end = new Date().getTime();
        const diffinsec = (end-start)/1000
        console.log("Execution time : ",diffinsec,'s');
    });

    proc.stdout.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log(" ::::: Error at all : ", err);
    });
} catch (err) {
    console.log(":::::::: getting error at mergeAllVideo() ", err);
}
```

}

Query is running successfully but no video file is being generated in the given directory. Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I to am working on this. my approach is a "for file in" Queue building one.

- pick the head of the queue (the first clip) and format it correctly
- start a "for file in" loop

  - format $file correctly
  - concatenate resulting file onto end of queue file